# Cordova.exec is not called in Worklight hybrid app ios

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight version 6.1.

I have created a native(iPhone) component inside a Hybrid app.
I also have 2 HTML pages: the default index.html and card.html.

I am able to navigate from index.html to card.html.
In card.html I have added a button called "Addcard". When clicking the "AddCard" button a JS function is called which in turn displays the native component through cordova plugin (cordova.exec):

```
cordova.exec(wrappedSuccess, failureCallback, "CardIOPGPlugin", "canScan", []);
```

From the native page, by using a Back button I am able to return to card.html, and from there to index.html.

The problem is, that now if I try again to navigate from index.html to card.html, the cordova.exec method is not working.

App Flow:

1. First page-index.html page, To navigate to card.html page form index.html page i am using `$("#HomePage").load("htmlpages/cardinfo.html", function(){});`
2. Second page is card.html, It has two buttons:

   - Back: To navigate to index.html page,
   - Add: Will call `Scancard()` in card.html, which in turn will call `canScan` in cardioplugin.js, which in turn call `cordova.exec(wrappedSuccess, failureCallback, "CardIOPGPlugin", "canScan", []);`
3. First flow index.html->card.html, all functionalities are working but when i navigate to index.html from card page using the above functionality and again navigate to card.html page add functionality is not working (cordova.exce is not called).

Comment: Can you upload a sample project recreating what you wrote in the question? It will be easier to debug it.

Comment: Sorry Idan,i could not able to upload sample project,it is difficult to recreate the flow,more dependency is there,it is refering many other files.can i share the screenshots?

Comment: just provide the code you're using, we can put a dummy plug-in instead

Comment: Idan is it possible to upload files in stackoverflow?

Comment: Idan will try to upload code file uisng drop box

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not reply back to the question in the comments for a long time, I went ahead and created an application that simulates your flow as close as I understand it to be.

For me the flow works correctly and cordova.exec executes at all times.
You can review the implementation yourself by downloading the Worklight 6.1.0.2 project from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/edn71leo5197i80/multipageexecuteplugin.zip?dl=0

Note that some files reside in the iphone\nativeResources folder as well so that you could easily run the app w/out any prior setup.

As for why it may happen to you:

1. Really need that test project to debug it...
2. Only other thing I can think of is that you somehow lose the context to Worklight, thus cordova.exec "suddenly" stop working.

It might be because you're re-loading the index.html file (I implemented this differently), but give this low chances to be the cause.